# Inserting data into a Django DB

Tags: django

I'm trying to use a regular python script to add data to a table that was created via the standard django process (start project/app/create model etc).

In the same DB, I set up another table with the same columns as the django DB to test on, and wrote a script that successfully parsed data and inserted it into that DB.

When I changed the table name so that the data would be written to the standard Django table, nothing was inserted and no error was thrown.

Is there something that prevents access to the Django tables that I'm unaware of?

Comment: No - database is a database. A Django created one shouldn't prevent you accessing it. I utlilze your use case all the time without issue. It is hard to say what your problem might be without more information.

Comment: Turns out I had to change the engine type to MyISAM for the mysql connector I was using.